# searchParams.get returning "Null" when values are present

Tags: javascript, url, parameter-passing

I'm trying to grab URL params from a page link to prepopulate a form in an iFrame, but am struggling with the params returning 'null' and need some guidance. So far, the script appears to work by populating the form with "null", however, it is unsuccessfully populating params that have valid values in my URL. The javascript below 'f.src' is scripting provided by my forms service.

(I apologize for the ugly console.logs, but am using those for troubleshooting.)

[Console Preview][1]

***UPDATE: With my updated code, per user suggestion, I updated my .get statements to specify the param with a string, but it's still returning 'null'.

````
try{
        var endpoint = "https://forms.myformsite.com/";
        console.log(endpoint);
        var url_string = "https://my.site.com/landingpage?fname=Jeff&lname=Bezos&email=jeff@amazon.com&company=Amazon&title=Founder"; /*window.location.href;*/
        console.log(url_string);
        var url = new URL(url_string);
        console.log(url_string);
        var fname = url.searchParams.get('fname');
        console.log(fname);
        var lname = url.searchParams.get('lname');
        console.log(lname);
        var email = url.searchParams.get('email');
        console.log(email);
        var company = url.searchParams.get('company');
        console.log(company);
        var title = url.searchParams.get('title');
        console.log(title);
        var formURL = endpoint+"&fname="+fname+"&lname="+lname+"&email="+email+"&company"+company+"&title="+title;
        console.log(formURL);
        var f = document.createElement("iframe");   
        f.src = formURL;
        console.log(f.src);
        f.style.border = "none";
        f.style.height = "878px";
        f.style.width = "90%";
        f.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease";
        var d = document.getElementById("divFormID");
        d.appendChild(f);
        window.addEventListener('message', function() {
            var evntData = event.data;
            if (evntData && evntData.constructor == String) {
                var zf_ifrm_data = evntData.split("|");
                if (zf_ifrm_data.length == 2) {
                    var zf_perma = zf_ifrm_data[0];
                    var zf_ifrm_ht_nw = (parseInt(zf_ifrm_data[2], 10) + 15) + "px";
                    var iframe = document.getElementById("divFormID").getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
                    if ((iframe.src).indexOf('formperma') > 0 && (iframe.src).indexOf(zf_perma) > 0) {
                        var prevIframeHeight = iframe.style.height;
                        if (prevIframeHeight != zf_ifrm_ht_nw) {
                            iframe.style.height = zf_ifrm_ht_nw;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, false);
    } catch (e) {}
})();```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z75q0.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjqoP.png
````

Answer (score 0):

For all `.get()` calls, you're passing in an (undefined) variable instead of a string:

```
var fname = url.searchParams.get(fname);
```

This should be:

```
var fname = url.searchParams.get('fname');
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight. However, when I make the corrections you specified, it's still returning 'null'.

Comment: What exactly is returning `null`? Not the `.get()` calls.

Comment: The params are not populating to the variables (i think). So the form gets generated with 'null' in the fields. 

My result:

var formURL = endpoint+"&fname="+fname+"&lname="+lname+"&email="+email+"&company"+company+"&title="+title;
        console.log(formURL); //  "https://forms.myformsite.com/?fname=null&lname=null&email=null&company=null&title=null"